# pdf form javascript doesn't work in MacOS Preview?

Tags: hyperref, mac, javascript, macos, textfield

I am trying to implement a simple word count script, but Preview seems to not want to run javascript. I do not know if there is something wrong with my LaTeX (I had a previous problem with Acrobat Reader where I just needed to specify names for the TextFields, so I thought it might be related to my code). Here is my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\TextField[name=tf, width=\linewidth, height=3\baselineskip,multiline=true%
,keystroke = {%
this.getField("wc").value = event.value.trim().split(/\\s+/).length;
}
]{Input:}\\

\TextField[name=wc,readonly=true]{Output:}

\end{document}
```

When the user types into the "Input" box, it should give the word count in the "Output" box. This seems to work in Acrobat Reader and PDFPenPro. It does not appear to work in MacOS Preview. Nothing is ever filled in the "Output" box.

Moreover, editing the document in Preview appears to break the functionality; if I edit the document in Preview and then open it in Acrobat Reader, the word count script no longer functions.

Is this my LaTeX code, or a Preview issue, or an interaction? Is there a workaround?

If it helps, I'm using MacOS 10.15.4 (19E266), and Preview 11.0 (999.4).

Comment: The short answer: JavaScript is only in Adobe Acrobat robust and reliable.

Comment: As its name suggests, Preview is a previewer.

Comment: @AlexG evidently not, because as I mentioned Preview seems to *break* the document.

Comment: Oh my, so one should better not use it.